# Argon and noble gases

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

- Helium
  [image: Helium]
- Neon
  [image: Neon]
- Argon
  [image: Argon]
- Krypton
  [image: Krypton]
- Xenon
  [image: Xenon]
- Radon
  [image: Radon]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are

> [Magic Eye images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Eye)

which

> each have a letter:
>
>  He: **O**
>  Ne: **Y**
>  Ar: **D**
>  Kr: **M**
>  Xe: **L**
>  Rn: **E**
>
>  These letters anagram to MELODY, which might be the intended answer? (I'm not seeing a 'nicer' way to get it, though. Rainbow ordering on the pictures gives YDMLOE, which isn't any better; alphabetical ordering on the elements also doesn't work.)

Comment: Spot on answer! :)